# VHDL using signals to hold temp values

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I know that signal assignments are done at the end of the process. But let's say that I have two signals "A" and "B". The value of A changes so frequently in my process (almost in every cycle) and B is used to hold the value of A as a temp value to assign it to some other signal in the next clock cycle. However, I don't want the value of B to change unless some certain thing happenes. So if I assign A to B once in the process, does the value of B get updated automatically whenever the value of A changes? If the answer is yes, how can I make B change its value only when an if statement holds? Does using a variable instead of a signal as B solve this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How about generating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You might well answer it yourself if you do.

Comment: You're being unclear. Illustrate with code. What's going on in the sensitivity list?

Comment: I don't think you understand what assignment within a process does at a slightly more fundamental level. If you assign `B <= A` within a process every time it runs, then at the end of the process (a 0 time difference) `B` will get the the value `A` had *upon entry* to the process. If you *only* assign `B <= A` within an `if` statement, then when the process runs but does not satisfy that `if` statement, `B` will hold it's previous value. Assuming your process is clocked, this will implement `B` in flip-flops. If it was an unclocked process, it will implement it with latches (bad).

Answer (score 0):

One of the main differences between signals and variables is that the variable assignment takes place immediately and the signal assignment occurs at the end of the process evaluation (normally end of a clock cycle).

When A and B are both declared as signals:

```
process (reset, clk)
begin
   if (reset = '1') then
      A <= '0';
      B <= '0';
   elsif rising_edge(clk) then

      A <= Some_Frequently_Changing_Signal;

      if ("certain thing happens") then
         B <= A;
      end if;

   end if;
end process;
```

When the if statement evaluates to true, B is assigned the value that A had upon entry to the process (which would be whatever Some_Frequently_Changing_Signal was during the previous clock cycle).

If we declare A as a variable instead of a signal:

```
process (reset, clk)
begin
   if (reset = '1') then
      A := '0';
      B <= '0';
   elsif rising_edge(clk) then

      A := Some_Frequently_Changing_Signal;

      if ("certain thing happens") then
         B <= A;
      end if;

   end if;
end process;
```

When the if statement evaluates to true, B is assigned A.  However, A holds the current value of Some_Frequently_Changing_Signal since a variable assignment takes place immediately.  This type of coding style is not recommended.  It would be better to just use:

```
process (reset, clk)
begin
   if (reset = '1') then
      B <= '0';
   elsif rising_edge(clk) then

      if ("certain thing happens") then
         B <= Some_Frequently_Changing_Signal;
      end if;

   end if;
end process;
```